# Шаблоны C++ , undefined reference to

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, стек

**stack.cpp**

```
//stack.cpp
#include "stack.h"

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    top = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T arg)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->value = arg;
    temp->next = top;
    top = temp;
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (top != nullptr)
    {
        T result = top->value;
        Node* temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        delete temp;
        return result;
    } else
        return 0;
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    while (top != nullptr)
        pop();
}
```

**stack.h**

```
//stack.h
#ifndef PROJECT_STACK_H
#define PROJECT_STACK_H

template <class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T value;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* top;
public:
    Stack();
    void push(T arg);
    T pop();
    ~Stack();
};


#endif //PROJECT_STACK_H
```

//main.cpp примерно следующего содержания:

```
Stack <char> s;
s.push('a');
```

компилирую через g++ так: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp stack.cpp`

Получаю следующие ошибки:

```
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `Stack<char>::Stack()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Stack<char>::Stack()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `Stack<char>::push(char)'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Stack<char>::push(char)'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `Stack<char>::push(char)'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Stack<char>::push(char)'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `Stack<char>::pop()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x49): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Stack<char>::pop()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `Stack<char>::pop()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x66): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Stack<char>::pop()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `Stack<char>::~Stack()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x9b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Stack<char>::~Stack()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `Stack<char>::~Stack()'
/tmp/ccvtzAEt.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xae): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Stack<char>::~Stack()'
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

То есть  undefined reference to `Stack<char>::Stack()` и undefined reference to `Stack<char>::push(char)` и undefined reference to `Stack<char>::~Stack()`

В чем проблема? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: вообще говоря, для таких случаев было предусмотрено ключевое слово **export**, но оно почему-то в популярных компиляторах не реализовано

Comment: @mymedia: `export` было недоспецифицировано в стандарте языка и реализовать его правильно было невозможно - никто просто не знал, что такое "правильно". В конечном итоге его убрали из языка: нет больше никакого `export` в С++.

Answer (score 7):

Ну откуда же при компиляции stack.cpp компилятору знать, что где-то, в совсем другом файле вам понадобится `Stack<char>`?

Не выносите реализацию **шаблонов** в отдельный файл, оставляйте ее в заголовочном файле.

Comment: Но ведь в stl реализация вынесена из хедеров

Comment: Вы так уверены? :)

Comment: @M Nikita: Вам показалось. Вынести из хедера можно (и нужно) только определения явно специализированных (explicit specialization) шаблонов. Но пока шаблон зависит хоть от одного шаблонного параметра - ему место в хедере.

Answer (score 7):

Либо не выносите определения шаблонов в отдельный файл (т.е. реализуйте все в заголовочном файле), либо не забывайте *включать* этот отдельный файл повсеместно, как включаются обычные заголовочные файлы.

На практике у обоих подходов есть свои поклонники. Но при этом давать файлу реализации расширение `.cpp` не принято - это все таки *включаемый*, а не отдельно компилируемый файл.

Скармливать ваш файл реализации непосредственно компилятору (`g++ stack.cpp`) бесполезно: определения шаблонов не порождают кода, в чем вы сможете убедиться взглянув на сгенерированный из `stack.cpp` объектный файл - он будет пуст.

**P.S.** Теоретически, вы можете оставить все как есть, но добавить в `stack.cpp` *явные инстанциации* вашего шаблона для всех требуемых типов аргументов. Т.е. в вашем случае достаточно добавить в `stack.cpp` строчку

```
template Stack<char>;
```

и все сразу заработает в оригинальном виде, при компиляции через ваше `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp stack.cpp`. Но, как вы сами понимаете, в общем случае это - не жизнеспособный подход, а специальная фича, предназначенная совсем для других целей.

Comment: наверное `template class Stack<char>;`